# UIImageView animation - using perform selector after delay to display last image in the array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

Basically, I have a UIImageView that will loop through 8 PNGs over 0.5 seconds. At the same time I start the animation, I do a performSelector with afterDelay of 0.5 seconds. So after my UIImageView has finished animating it will call animationTickDone which will set the last image hidden to no.

Here's the code anyway:

```
.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIView *scannedView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *animatedTickLast;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *scannedView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *animatedTickLast;

.m
-(void)Found{
        [self.view addSubview:scannedView];
        [animatedTickLast setHidden:YES];
        //place animated tick images into an array
        NSMutableArray *animatedTickImages;
        animatedTickImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSUInteger nimages = 0;
        for (nimages=0; nimages<8; nimages++){
            NSString *tickImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tick_%d.png", (nimages + 1)];
            [animatedTickImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:tickImageName]];
        }
        //set up animated tick
        UIImageView *animatedTick = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(98, 213, 125, 90)];
        [animatedTick setAnimationImages:animatedTickImages];
        [animatedTick setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [animatedTick setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        [animatedTick startAnimating];
        NSLog(@"animation started");
        [self performSelector:@selector(animationTickDone) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
        [scannedView addSubview:animatedTick];
        NSLog(@"animation added into view");
        [animatedTickImages release];
}
- (void)animationTickDone{
    NSLog(@"delay function begins");
    [animatedTickLast setHidden:NO];
    sleep(1); //sleep so that scannedView stays on screen for at least 1.5 seconds (0.5 after animation + 1 from sleep);
}
```

Now, the problem. The animation itself is fine, and works great. But when Found() is first called, animatedTickLast will become visible after the animation. But when ever Found is called again afterwords, animatedTickDone never appears again, it's just an empty space.

After hours looking around the web searching and playing with it, I just cannot understand what the issue is as to why it doesn't appear. I thought at one point sleep() was getting called before my animatedTickLast could get chance to set hidden to no, but after removing sleep() it still didn't work.

Driving me nuts now so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want an image after the animaton in the UIImageView. Just set the image before the animation and you are fine!

```
[animatedTick setAnimationImages:animatedTickImages];
[animatedTick setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[animatedTick setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
[animatedTick setImage:theImageYouLikeToHave];
[animatedTick startAnimating];
```

Comment: Thanks Pfitz. Added `[animatedTick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_8.png"]];` now and it's great, so easy, never came up when searching things like 'how to show last image'. Saves me some effort. However, strangely, the same things more or less happens. When initially calling Found(), it works like a charm. But once I call it again, it now just shows the tick_8.png and no animation (I'm guessing the animation is animating over the top of tick_8.png but can't be seen). Any ideas?

Comment: can you try and just call `startAnimating` the second time?

Comment: I think you could be on the right lines with this, I moved all the animatedTick bits except startAnimating into viewDidLoad but then realised part of my script reloads this. Something I'm going to change now and then get back to you if it works. Likely in the morning. Thanks for your help so far though!! :) But if you think me moving those other bits to viewDidLoad so they're only called once and then keep call startAnimating whenever will work, then that's what I'll do

Comment: I've now tried calling just `startAnimating` the second time, but still the same thing. Works first time but not after. I changed `setImage` to tick_last.png which I coloured in black (the rest of the animation is in white). Now I can see, on anything after the first calling, the black tick shows instantly, and then I can see the series of white ticks animating over the top of it. Don't suppose you have any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Pfitz. This all helped solve my query in most parts and then a bit I had to do in the rest of my code because of the way it was calling Found()